# Is there a way to view .ipynb file changes on github but not in JSON format?

Tags: git, github, jupyter

So I'm new to Jupyter and one thing I've noticed is that when people make pull requests on GitHub, the .ipynb code is viewed in the raw JSON format which isn't really human readable. I would like to be able to easily view highlighted pull request changes but in the "rendered" format. I've looked around a bit and I've found something along the lines of what I'm looking for ([reviewNB](https://www.reviewnb.com/)). Is reviewNB the industry standard for reviewing Jupyter code? Are there other alternatives out there that people like using?